# unable to restore .sql file into mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql version is 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 and my test.sql file contains

```
-- Host: localhost    Database: test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

CREATE TABLE `auth_user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`last_login` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 ..................................
```

when am trying to restore data using mysql -uroot -ppassword test < test.sql it showing

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 140: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
   to use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL,`is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   `username` varchar(150' at line 4
```

Error is occuring due to single quotes or might be mysql version difference . 
Please help me out

Comment: your ``CREATE`` statement doesn't end. There should be a closing bracket ``)`` instead of the last ``,``

Comment: Probably best to show the end of the statement too, in case people think you forgot the closing brackets (I hope that's not the error).

Comment: Show us the complete code.

Comment: Please go through it i have added more code for better understanding

Comment: now it look like entirely different code

Comment: @Dimgold I agree with your comment, so I rolled back the latest edit because the question simply did not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has no size try:

```
-- Host: localhost    Database: test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

CREATE TABLE `auth_user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 ..................................
```

Comment: Not entirely correct, it depends on your MySQL version. v5.7 does, v5.5 dos not. See duplicate topic.